# `and` author separator in `.bib` file doesn't work correctly as `,` ( using xepersian)

Tags: biblatex, biber, xepersian

Hi

Actually I want to write my references in latex using `xepersian` package.
Actually I searched for separating article's authors on the internet. I found out that I should use `and` between authors. However in my code it does'nt work and it compile the authors with 'and' not the separator `,`

my code:

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}


\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont{B Zar}

\addbibresource{Refrences.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{}






 \begin{document}
 \nocite{*}
 \maketitle
در زیر عنوان های مقالات درس سمینار با موضوع "یتسدذسردتس " ارائه می گردد:
\begin{latin}

%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%\bibliography{.bib}
\printbibliography
\end{latin} 

 \end{document}
```

and my `refrence.bib`:

```
@article{one,
author = "Alexandru and Alexander",
title = {Recovery Conditions and Sampling Strategies for Network Lasso},
journal = {Comm. Mag.},
issue_date = {March 1994},
volume = {32},
number = {3},
month = mar,
year = {1994},
issn = {0163-6804},
pages = {22--33},
numpages = {12},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/35.267438},
doi = {10.1109/35.267438},
acmid = {2294265},
publisher = {IEEE Press},
address = {Piscataway, NJ, USA},
}
```

I would appreciate for you solutions

Comment: I cannot test your MWE for the lack of the proper font. But it looks like the "and" you find there is the regular delimiter before the last name in a list. If you want to be sure load `babel` with another language other than english, you will see the output delimiter is a localized string.  So I'd say it looks your code works pretty much as expected. Given that, it shouldn't be difficult to change this delimiter to a comma. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Actually I want it to be written as a standard form (I mean automatically and with correct syntax I'd like to get the standard output  ).In addition change the font to any font which you have , I think the problem will exist as well

Comment: The "and" is the standard output for the English language (though for US English it also gets the Oxford comma as ", and"). If what you want is the default, it looks correct. I tested your code without the `xepersian` parts (as I said, I don't have your font) and it worked fine for me here, the result was the expected. If you want to convince yourself, test your bib file with `Alexandru and Alexander and Alexandrei`. The result in the output should be "Alexandru, Alexander and Alexandrei", as expected.

Comment: Now would you give me a hint about putting comma between names in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage{xepersian} % unfortunately, I don't have your font installed.

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

%\settextfont{B Zar}

\addbibresource{Refrences.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

But I don't recommend that you do it. The final delimiter being "and" is pretty standard, I'd say you wanna keep it. Notice that already in your example you have a case which will fatally be misread. You have two authors named respectively "Alexandru" and "Alexander" which will be rendered, if you change the delimiter as "Alexandru, Alexander". That will be read, by anyone I know, as *one* author with first name "Alexander" and surname "Alexandru".

Comment: `\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}` would also work.